# Clear DB Log File in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am looking for a tsql or query which will clear the transaction log file/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should first find out why it is large.....also try searching SO first.. Has been asked many times already...

Comment: I did but people always say Shrink DB or something. I also did some googling but couldn't find what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
DUMP TRANSACTION [database_name] WITH NO_LOG
```

Comment: don't ever run anything on your database that you do not completely understand, and that you have not completely checked out.  look it up in the manual.  **If you just run stuff you find on the internet you are open to a social engineering attack.** would you run the `DROP DATABASE .....`

Comment: Late comment sorry: DUMP has been deprecated http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187315(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: @gbn, hopefully the OP would read the manual as recommended above and find that this would work for them now, but they would need to learn something else for the long term future.

Answer (score 0):

' execute with admin priveleges

> BACKUP LOG db_name WITH NO_LOG
>
> GO
>
> DBCC SHRINKDATABASE( db_name, 0)
>
> GO